# JAVASCRIPT = ¿Cómo obtener un recuento de las horas que ya pasaron en el día?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs, javascript-metodo

Quiero hacer un método en donde yo generé una lista de horas que ya han pasado en el día, es decir justo en este momento son las 10:00 AM, entonces yo quiero obtener una lista de las que ya pasaron antes de las 10:00 AM, algo así:

- 1:00 AM
- 2:00 AM
- 3:00 AM
- .
- .
- .
- 9:00 AM

He estado investigando un poco de cómo puedo hacerlo en JS, hasta el momento se que `now()` te trae la hora actual, `setHour` actualiza la hora y `getHours`obtiene la hora actual igual que now

```
const tiempoTranscurrido = Date.now();
const hoy = new Date(tiempoTranscurrido);
hoy.setHours(hoy.getHours() - tiempoTranscurrido)
console.log('tiempoTranscurrido', hoy);
```

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer? Estaba pensando en restar las horas que ya pasaron de la hora actual, ¿alguien conoce como? Porfavor si alguien me explica

Comment: `for(let i = 0; i<hoy.getHours(); i++) console.log("La hora " + (i + 1) + " ya ha pasado");`.

Comment: Genial! Funciona bien, pero actualmente el ciclo te dice que hora paso ¿cómo podria obtener una lista con esas horas que ya pasaron?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es necesario que uses `Date.now` puedes convertir los milisegundos a una fecha completa usando el constructor `Date`, de esta manera después podemos usar `getHours` y usar un bucle para contar desde la medianoche hasta la hora actual para saber cuántas horas han transcurrido y saber cuáles son

```js
const now = Date.now();

const nowDate = new Date(now);
const hours = nowDate.getHours();
const horasTranscurridas = [];

for(let i = 1; i <= hours; i++) {
  horasTranscurridas.push(i);
}

console.log("Han transcurrido "+horasTranscurridas.length+" horas: "+horasTranscurridas.join(", "))
```

Comment: `new Date(Date.now())` es exactamente lo mismo que `new Date()` a secas. El constructor vacío devuelve una fecha actual

Comment: Genial! Funciona bien, muchisimas gracias por su ayuda y explicarme, tengo una pregunta ¿cómo puedo formatear el resultado? Con moment intente hacerlo, pero no me funciono del todo bien, 

let timeList = horasTranscurridas.map(hourAsDate => {
      console.log('moment', moment(hourAsDate).format('h:mm a'));
    })

Comment: @Izlia Si te refieres a formatear la hora en un formato `AM` o `PM`, como _1AM_, _13PM_, etc, puedes usar un [operador ternario](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) para comprobar si el número que estamos iterando es mayor que 12, si es asíe añadiremos _AM_, sino _PM_, esto se hace en la línea donde ocurre el `push`, puede ser algo así: `horasTranscurridas.push(i+(i > 12 ? "PM" : "AM"));`